# Java NoClassDefFoundError with Ant

Tags: java, ant, classpath

I have a third-party `.jar` file in a `res/lib` folder. The ANT `build.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="my.project" basedir="." default="build">
    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="build/classes"/>

    <path id="master-classpath">
        <fileset dir="res/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
    </path>

    <target name="build">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <javac destdir="${build.dir}" optimize="true">
            <src path="${src.dir}"/>
            <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
</project>
```

The `.java` file is the following:

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

public class IO {
    public static void readCSVFile(File file) throws IOException {
        FileReader in = new FileReader(file);
        Iterable<CSVRecord> record = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(in);
    }
}
```

The compile is OK, but I got a runtime error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat`. I think something is wrong with the classpath, but it seems ok to me.

UPDATE:

It is running if I use `java -cp path;. Main`. I have tried to write an ANT script to run it:

```
<target name="run">
    <java classname="Main">
        <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

I write `ant run` in the command line, I get `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` and nothing happens.

Comment: How are you running the main class?

Comment: Your snippet shows only the compilation with javac task. How do you start your compiled class ? Via ant java task or outside your ant script ? When starting with ant java task simply reuse the pathreference master-classpath otherwise you need to declare your classpath with commandline parameter => java -cp ... The javac compile doesn't slurp the dependencies into the class file.

Comment: To make 'something happen' you have to expand your Main class. f.e. if you put some System.out.println("Main class called..") in you'll see it in ant output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your buildfile *compiles* your code and includes the third-party Jar in the classpath so that the compiler could be able to locate the classes on which your code depends (e.g. `org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord`).

Similarly, when *running* your main class via the `java` your JVM needs to know where the third-party classes exist. Otherwise the classloader will fail to load these classes. So in your example, you should still call the main class as follows:

```
java -cp pathtoyourlib;. Main
```

In other words, these are two different "classpath" concepts: one classpath is used by the compiler to know where to locate every referenced class in every class to be compiled, while the other is used by the JVM to know where to load classes when they are dynamically invoked.

Comment: Thanks, its working now. You know a short way to write an ANT script to run it, so that I do not have to add the -cp again and again. I tried a way, which I'll include in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your class has no (visible) main method

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    IO.readCSVFile(File file)
}
```

You need to pass the classpath when running the file

```
java -cp yourclasspath
```

Comment: Run it with java -cp yourfullclasspath Main

Answer (score 0):

You state that the compile is ok, but you don't show how you're running the java program..... So to be clear, ANT completes without error? This is a problem running the java program post compilation from the command line?

If I'm correct then there are two problems:

1. Your java program has no main class (required then running from commandline)
2. The jars your program depends on my be included on the classpath when running the java program.

Comment: ANT completes without error. The program has a Main class. I run it from the command line like `java Main` and there I got the error.